# Changing brightness of photos command-line

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, webcam, ubuntu-18.04

I need to take a photo with my USB webcam in Ubuntu 18.04. I did this in three different ways.

1. `streamer -s [640x480] -f jpeg -c /dev/video2 -o image.jpeg`
2. Cheese application
3. `ffmpeg -f oss -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video2 out.jpeg`

Each of these three methods has different brightness options. The first method has good brightness, but there's no good brightness with the other two methods. How can this problem be solved?

I need a terminal command to take a photo and use it in Python.

Comment: I had a similar problem in Ubuntu 18.04 with raw photos from my camera which I solved with [Darktable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508071/open-raw-image-files-in-gimp/1082805#1082805) application. The screenshots will explain how the photos look. I don't know the answer to this question, but you could try Darktable too and see if it works with your webcam. Different cameras have different outputs, so you have to try it and see. That's how I got it to work was I tried everything and picked the best looking results. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it except with a GUI app.